# Comparing variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm using simple jQuery to compare two variables, but every time it is yielding false result. Here is the code piece:

```
 var fromIM = $("#passwordFroma").val();
 loadContent(passwordValentered);
 var encrypt = document.getElementById("prtCnt").value;
 alert("ajax call " + encrypt);
 alert(encrypt == fromIM);
```

In the above code piece,

> passwordFroma is a hidden text field.
>  passwordValentered is a text box
>   to get user input.
>  prtCnt is a hidden field.

Also, *loadContent(passwordValentered)* function is an ajax call which sets the value for hidden field *prtCnt*. This is confirmed from the first alert. But, when I compare the values in second alert, I always get the result as false.
Please let me know where am I going wrong! I'm using jQuery 1.9.

Comment: Have you checked to see what `encrypt` and `fromIM` look like *(i.e. their values)* in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. Make sure you do the `alert(encrypt == fromIM)` call in the success function of the ajax call.

Comment: I agree. You should do something like `alert(fromIM + " == " + encrypt + "?"); to see if the values are what you think they are.

Comment: @summea yes..I've checked them and they are the same!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generated field with id `prtCnt` is generated asynchronously (AJAX), therefore it's not accessible immediately after the call to `loadContent(passwordValentered);`

```
var fromIM = $("#passwordFroma").val();
// Sends AJAX
loadContent(passwordValentered);
// AJAX is not finished here
var encrypt = document.getElementById("prtCnt").value;
alert("ajax call " + encrypt);
alert(encrypt == fromIM);
```

You have to pass a callback to `loadContent`

```
var fromIM = $("#passwordFroma").val();
loadContent(passwordValentered, function(){
   var encrypt = document.getElementById("prtCnt").value;
   alert("ajax call " + encrypt);
   alert(encrypt == fromIM);
});
```

And modify your `loadContent` so that it calls the given callback from the success handler of `$.ajax`

Comment: Ok Juan, let me try that. As I'm pretty new to Ajax and jQuery, so this all might take some time and it's already 2:00am at my place, I'll try it tomorrow and will update you soon. Thanks for the suggestion!!